# While sending arab content in mail the receiver in box displaying special character (in outlook mailer)

Tags: php, html, email, outlook

On form submition am generating a mail, The mail content is in arab language.
In mail template I added the attributes like this

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

When user receiving the mail in google the message showing properly without any mistakes, but while receiving the same mail in outlook mail application the message displaying like special characters(not a human readable format)
ex:

> "Ø´ÙƒØ±Ø§Ù‹ Ù„Ùƒ Ø¹Ù„Ù‰ ØªØ³Ø¬ÙŠÙ„Ùƒ ÙˆØ§Ù„Ø¥Ù†Ø¶Ù…Ø§Ù… Ø¥Ù„ÙŠÙ†Ø§ ÙÙŠ Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù… ØªØ§Ù„ÙŠ Ù„ØªØ".